# Register clojure.specs from a map

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have a map of clojure.specs that I want to use to validate my requests in runtime like this:

```
{::num-id int?
 :project-spec/id ::num-id
 :project-spec/name (s/and string? #((< (count %) 24)))
 :project-spec/project (s/keys :req-un [:project-spec/id :project-spec/name])}
```

I can use any of those specs in runtime to validate using `s/valid?`, except the `project-spec/project` one. That one requires all others to be registered in global spec registry to work properly. When I try to register spec using simple `doseq` function if fails since I pass local variables to `s/def` macros and it doesn't resolve variables to the value before expanding the macros.

```
(doseq [[name spec] spec-map]
    (s/def name spec))
```

I tried to create macros to eval variables before passing them to s/def macros, but that one fails with `CompilerException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't eval locals`.

```
(defmacro reg-spec
  [name spec]
  `(s/def ~(eval name) ~(eval spec)))

(doseq [[name spec] spec-map]
    (reg-spec name spec))
```

The last thing I tried is to eval variables when passing to `s/def` but that fails spec validation.

```
(s/def (eval spec-name) (eval spec-spec))
 CompilerException java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: k must be 
 namespaced keyword or resolvable symbol (c/and (ident? k) (namespace k))
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do? Or am I misunderstanding something obvious? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to give the specs a *name* via `s/def`? An important aspect of spec is strong/namespaced names. Your example gives them names in a sense, but only as keys in that map. I'd `s/def` them all. I fixed a few errors in the example above. Your map keys are namespaced, so `s/keys` should use `:req` instead of `:req-un`.

```
(s/def ::num-id integer?)
(s/def :project-spec/id ::num-id)
(s/def :project-spec/name (s/and string? #(< (count %) 24)))
(s/def :project-spec/project (s/keys :req [:project-spec/id :project-spec/name]))
```

You could still build your map of specs if you wanted, but the keys/values would be identical.

```
(s/conform :project-spec/project
           {:project-spec/id 1, :project-spec/name "123"})
;;=> {:project-spec/id 1, :project-spec/name "123"}
```

Comment: The goal I'm trying to achieve is to reuse specs both in ClojureScript and Clojure part of an application and I want to have access to the in runtime, so I can do conform and validation. I also want to reuse them for functions that will work with this data. So, having them as a map makes that handy, but I'm struggling to register them to global registry from map.

Comment: Also, even though you put `req-un` keys that are not namespaced, you're still required to provide namespaced keys there, so spec can validate values corresponding to keys.

Comment: @SergeyShvets check out [this article](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2017/3/24/3xeif9bxaom78qyzwssgwz1leuorh4#sharing-specs-across-the-front-and-back-end). I think it describes exactly what you're trying to do for reusing specs across CLJ/CLJS. Also, I'm not sure storing the specs in a map has any advantages over just `s/def`ing them in a namespace.